# Epplus, Out of memory

Tags: c#

Sorry for my English. I used the library Epplus and I really like it. But I've got a problem: Out of Memory. Need to write large amounts of data, no matter what. I want to know is it possible to append to the end of the Excel file is not stored in the memory of all. Or create multiple files and then concatenate into one file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the application 32 or 64 bit? 64 bit would give a larger address space to work with and let you use the swap file.

Comment: If the application will be 64, I do not understand how it can help, because with each passing day becomes more and more data. And those extra few megabytes, is the solution for a few days.

Comment: 64 bit gives you up to 8TB in local address space, and if your getting that much data you probably want to be storing it in a database.

Comment: I thought that capture such a huge amount opertivnoy memory is not the best solution ((Can there be any other libraries to solve this problem?

Comment: Excel is not the proper storage medium for this amount of data. You need an actual database. There have to be other tools in your toolbox; not everything can be made to look like a nail so you can use your hammer.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Excel does not support the data in large quantities. But still provide reports to Excel for customers is very convenient.

Comment: Anything you say about libraries: ExcelLibrary, NPOI

Comment: However when providing reports in excel you don't neccicarily need to give them all the data, the excel sheet could contain a summary

Answer (score 0):

1)if you retrieve your data from database
use a datareader instead of datatable

2)write the excel to a temp file, delete it after done(if it's web environment, use response.writefile then delete it)

3)write the header first then append data to it
something like this (using my phone to type this)

```
var pck = new ExcelPackage();
var ws = pck.AddSheet("sheet1");
//write header here
pck.saveas(fileinfo);
pck.dispose(); // not sure if function existed
pck= new excelpage(fileino.fullname);
ws = pck.worksheets[1];
var rowIndex =0;
while (reader.read())
{
    if (++rowindex % 100000 == 0)
    {
       // save and re-open
    }
    //write row here
}
pck.save();
//dispose / send file / delete file etc
```